# Issue with spring '19 release for iteration over input field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx, spring19

i have bunch of lightning inputFields that i am using in iteration and one lightning input field which is outside of the itteration and aura:id for all the  input fields are same. But when on click of button i try to iteration over all the input fields with "component.find('aura:id')" i am able to get only one field which is out side of the itteration.

This issue is coming only with spring '19. IT is working fine in winter release.

CODE :

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="{!v.objectName}" recordTypeId="{!v.recordTypeId}">
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6" class="{!v.availabelRecordTypes.length > 1 ? '':'slds-hide'}">                
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="sObjectRecordTypeInputFieldForm" class="slds-hide" fieldName="RecordTypeId" value="{!v.selectedRecordType}"/>                
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <aura:iteration aura:id="iteration" items="{!v.fieldDetails}" var="field">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="sObjectInputFieldForm" class="{!field.requiredClass}" fieldName="{!field.fieldName}" />                    
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Click Event of button i am calling method which will loop through all the input fields

```
getFieldValue: function(component, event, helper) {
    var inputFieldValue, inputFields, isValid;
    inputFields = component.find("sObjectInputFieldForm");
    isValid = true;
    for (var i in inputFields) {            
        var fieldName = inputFields[i].get("v.fieldName");              
     }        
  }
```

Error i am getting is here :
[image]

I have debug the code and find out that i am getting only one field in spring org where as i am getting list of fields in winter org.

Help me out!!!!